# How to open one script with another

Tags: applescript

This might be fairly easy to answer. I have two scripts (i.e. `ScriptA.app` and `ScriptB.app`). My goal is to open `ScriptB.app` from `ScriptA.app`. I have tried this:

```
--ScriptA.app
tell application "ScriptB.app" to activate
```

But all I got was a window asking me `Where is ScriptB.app?` I scrolled through the list of applications but could not find `ScriptB.app` or `ScriptA.app` for that matter. I thought that was odd, as I saved both scripts as `Applications`. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I tried this, and it works for me when both scripts are saved (as .app files) in the Applications folder. Maybe yours are being saved somewhere else?

Comment: I wish I could accept comments as answers (saving in the Applications folder worked like a charm)... Thanks :)

Comment: I know this is probably a waste of time for you, but could you put your comment into an answer? I want to credit you for your good answer. :)

Comment: Now I've tried with either A or B on the desktop, _and it still works_! So there must have been some other reason...

Comment: Out of interest, did you also try specifying the full path to ScriptB rather than just "ScriptB.app"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried this, saving both apps in the Applications folder, it worked fine.

Also it still works if I move either A or B or both to the desktop.

Comment: Who knows, could have been a glitch. But from now on I'll save my apps in the `Applications` folder if I want to do something like this again. Thanks a lot. :)